# invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII) in a chef recipe

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Im trying to do a postgresql base back up via bash chef resources. Below is my code and im getting the following error. When i deploy them. Any thoughts why.

```
$PGDATA = "node['fc_db']['postgres']['pg_data']"

bash "backup master db" do
user "postgres"
code <<-EOH
  initdb –D  –-no-locale –-encoding=UTF8
  pg_ctl –D #{$PGDATA} start
  psql –c "SELECT pg_start_backup('initial backup for SR')" template1
  tar cvf pg_base_backup.tar #{$PGDATA}
  psql –c "SELECT pg_stop_backup()" template1
EOH
end
```

Comment: The error are :  FATAL: Cookbook file recipes/pg.rb has a ruby syntax error:
FATAL: /recipes/wal-e.rb:8: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
FATAL: /recipes/wal-e.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line in the code :

```
 initdb –D  –-no-locale –-encoding=UTF8
```

Should be:

```
 initdb –D  --no-locale --encoding=UTF8
```

Comment: there are changes in the line "-" on --no-locale & ----encoding=UTF8, that was messing the interpreter to understand the command.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Ruby are you using? If not 2.x.x, try adding `# encoding: UTF-8` on top of your wal-e.rb?

Comment: I found the error it was the "--" in the command im issuing. Thanks for the reply.